Как правильно написать функцию, что бы каждая кнопка по клику выдавала своё описание? А на данный момент все одним разом показывает
Я пробовала писать такие же функции js, но не работает как нужно
 <template>
<div class="flex justify-center items-center">
    <div class="relative my-7 mr-7">
    <button @click="toggleA" class="relative z-10 block rounded-md bg-red-200 p-1 focus: outline-none">
      Велосипеды
    </button>
    <div @click="toggleA" class="fixed inset-0 h-full w-full z-10 "></div>
    <div v-if="isA" class="absolute w-48 mt-2 right-0 bg-yellow-300 rounded-md shadow-xl z-20">
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Женские велосипеды</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Мужские велосипеды</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Детские велосипеды</a>    
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="relative my-7 mr-7">
    <button @click="toggleA" class="relative z-10 block rounded-md bg-red-200 p-1 focus: outline-none">
      Аксессуары
    </button>
    <div @click="toggleA" class="fixed inset-0 h-full w-full z-10 "></div>
    <div v-if="isA" class="absolute w-48 mt-2 right-0 bg-yellow-300 rounded-md shadow-xl z-20">
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Велогаджеты</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Насосы</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Фляги</a>    
    </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="relative my-7 mr-7">
    <button @click="toggleA" class="relative z-10 block rounded-md bg-red-200 p-1 focus: outline-none">
      Экипировка
    </button>
    <div @click="toggleA" class="fixed inset-0 h-full w-full z-10 "></div>
    <div v-if="isA" class="absolute w-48 mt-2 right-0 bg-yellow-300 rounded-md shadow-xl z-20">
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Защита</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Обувь</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Одежда</a>    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data()
 {
  return {
    isA: false,
  };
 },
 methods: {
  toggleA(){
    this.isA = !this.isA;
  },
 }
 };
</script>


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Здравствуйте! Не нужно создавать новые вопросы похожие на старые. Так же опишите пожалуйста подробно, что конкретно работает не так. Что вы ожидаете? Что происходит на самом деле?
Могу попробовать помочь и предположу (не уверен, я не работал с vue.js никогда), что можно создать подобные isA переменные (например isB, isC и т.д., простой пример, не лучшее решение), и завязать отдельные кнопки и div-ы на свои переменные. То есть 1 кнопка и div работают со своим is* и toggle*

Я создавала и другие isB, isC

Так же прописывала функцию с джавой, и ничего не работало

Просто сейчас, все кнопки работают по одному клику, а хотелось бы что бы каждая кнопка работала раздельно. Не понимаю что нужно вписать в джаву, что бы работало как нужно .

Ищите в интернете курсы для начинающих по Vue - этот ресурс не образовательный.
Вам нужно с нуля получить понимание  - что такое Vue и в чем его главные "фишки".

Как правильно написал Павел, нужно завести свои переменные для каждой кнопки:
<template>
<div class="flex justify-center items-center">
    <div class="relative my-7 mr-7">
    <button @click="toggleA" class="relative z-10 block rounded-md bg-red-200 p-1 focus: outline-none">
      Велосипеды
    </button>
    <div @click="toggleA" class="fixed inset-0 h-full w-full z-10 "></div>
    <div v-if="isA" class="absolute w-48 mt-2 right-0 bg-yellow-300 rounded-md shadow-xl z-20">
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Женские велосипеды</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Мужские велосипеды</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Детские велосипеды</a>    
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="relative my-7 mr-7">
    <button @click="toggleB" class="relative z-10 block rounded-md bg-red-200 p-1 focus: outline-none">
      Аксессуары
    </button>
    <div @click="toggleB" class="fixed inset-0 h-full w-full z-10 "></div>
    <div v-if="isB" class="absolute w-48 mt-2 right-0 bg-yellow-300 rounded-md shadow-xl z-20">
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Велогаджеты</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Насосы</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Фляги</a>    
    </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="relative my-7 mr-7">
    <button @click="toggleC" class="relative z-10 block rounded-md bg-red-200 p-1 focus: outline-none">
      Экипировка
    </button>
    <div @click="toggleC" class="fixed inset-0 h-full w-full z-10 "></div>
    <div v-if="isC" class="absolute w-48 mt-2 right-0 bg-yellow-300 rounded-md shadow-xl z-20">
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Защита</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Обувь</a>
    <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm capitalize hover:bg-black hover:text-white">Одежда</a>    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data()
 {
  return {
    isA: false,
    isB: false,
    icC: false
  };
 },
 methods: {
  toggleA(){
    this.isA = !this.isA;
  },
  toggleB(){
    this.isB = !this.isB;
  },
  toggleC(){
    this.isC = !this.isC;
  },
 }
 };
</script>


Лучше всего создать отдельный компонент и подключать его, но для начального понимания - ок)
